# why does autocorrect changes code when I save the file and then showing error?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

The problem occurs when I save file written with typscript it changes code and shows error

**package.json:**

```
"scripts": 
{ "dev": "npm run build:icons && vite --host", 
"build": "npm run build:icons && vite build", 
"preview": "vite preview --port 5050", 
"typecheck": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
 "lint": "eslint . -c .eslintrc.js --fix --rulesdir eslint-internal- 
 rules/ --ext .ts,.js,.vue,.tsx,.jsx",
"build:icons": "tsc -b src/@iconify && node src/@iconify/build-- 
 icons.js" }
```

**App.vue before saving:**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useThemeConfig } from '@core/composable/useThemeConfig'

const { syncInitialLoaderTheme, syncVuetifyThemeWithTheme: syncConfigThemeWithVuetifyTheme, isAppRtl } = useThemeConfig()

// ℹ️ Sync current theme with initial loader theme
syncInitialLoaderTheme()
syncConfigThemeWithVuetifyTheme()
</script>

<template>
  <VLocaleProvider :rtl="isAppRtl">
    <VApp>
      <VMain>
        <RouterView />
      </VMain>
    </VApp>
  </VLocaleProvider>
</template>
```

**App.vue after saving (adds semi-colon in 2 line):**
*then it shows this error*

module "d:/rh_app/vuexy/vue_version/full-version/src/@core/composable/useThemeConfig"
Extra semicolon.eslintsemi
Extra semicolon.eslint@typescript-eslint/semi

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useThemeConfig } from '@core/composable/useThemeConfig';

const { syncInitialLoaderTheme, syncVuetifyThemeWithTheme: syncConfigThemeWithVuetifyTheme, isAppRtl } = useThemeConfig()

// ℹ️ Sync current theme with initial loader theme
syncInitialLoaderTheme()
syncConfigThemeWithVuetifyTheme()
</script>

<template>
  <VLocaleProvider :rtl="isAppRtl">
    <VApp>
      <VMain>
        <RouterView />
      </VMain>
    </VApp>
  </VLocaleProvider>
</template>
```

Comment: Some ESlint/Prettier conflict I think.

Comment: Can you provide information about your build environment? IDE, safe actions, lint tool, compiler etc. The message seems to be from the lint tool and not from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You are running ESLint with the option --fix, which changes the source file according to the given rules, see [ESLint CLI docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/command-line-interface).

If you run the lint script a second time, there should be no error because the file has already be changed to match the rules. If there still is an error, there must be something wrong with the lint rules.

I would expect no errors if you use the modified source file in the buildscript.